# 'Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined' in mongodb and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Ive been getting a type error with my collection function that was working previously.

This code was working previously in my other project. I just ended up recycling alot of the code and now ive been getting this error. My mongodb connection code is in another file and is connected.

```
  var expect = require('chai').expect;
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
  var mongo    = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var db       = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

module.exports = function (app ,db) {
    db.collection.insertOne({
    "title": req.body.title,
    "_id": Math.random
  }).touchEvent(doc =>
    res.status(200).json({
      "status":"success",
     "_id": req.body._id,
      "title": req.body.title
    })).catch(err => {throw err;});
  })
};
```

The exact error message is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined". Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Just to clarify, my db.collection command is the one that is triggering the error.

Comment: The error indicates that `db` is undefined.  Which means `MongoClient` and `mongo` are undefined, too.  See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/69660

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Make db variable global and call it inside function like this

```
global.db       = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
module.exports = function (app) {
    db.collection.insertOne({
       "title": req.body.title,
        "_id": Math.random
     }).touchEvent(doc => res.status(200).json({
      "status":"success",
     "_id": req.body._id,
      "title": req.body.title
    })).catch(err => {throw err;});
  })
};
```

Check [here](https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `db` in the line `db.collection.insertOne(` is whatever is passed into the function, not the `db` defined earlier in the file. This might be confusing since both variables are named `db`, but in fact they are two different things.

For more info on JavaScript scopes see: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Your comment was helpful however, I removed the db variable from the export function and I was still getting the same error. Thank you for your input